# How to implement Handle for binary heaps?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was going through this pdf http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~anikolov/CSC265F18/binomial-heaps.pdf   .In second page last paragraph the pdf discusses about "storing  a  handle  to  the  corresponding  application  object in each mergeable-heap element, as well as a handle to corresponding mergeable-heap element in each application object."

Can anyone help me out regarding how handle can be used to return a pointer to the node so that the  pointer can be passed to functions DECREASE-KEY and DELETE of Binary heaps .

Thank you .

Comment: When they say "handle", they mean "something equivalent to a pointer".

Comment: @Matt thanks for the reply . In Fibonacci heaps there is no search algorithm so by using handle a given Node is passed to  DECREASE-KEY and DELETE functions . I just want to know how to implement this concept of handle so that I can avoid searching for a node before deleting it .

Comment: I have written a recursive function to find a node with given key in fibonacii heaps . But the search function depends on the position of node since there is no order of how keys are stored in fibonacii heaps . It just maintains min or max heap property .  I want to know how handle can store Nodes location so that I can retrieve a Node without using the search function .

Comment: Why don't you just use a pointer to the node as the handle?

Comment: @Matt thank you for the idea  . Can you please share any example code ?

Comment: @Matt . I implemented the handle concept .As you know there is no support for pointers in java , I used a HashMap<Integer,Node> that stores keys as integer and Node as the keys value . So no more search algorithm is required for Fibonacci heaps in order to delete a key , just pass the key value to hashmap handle object to retrieve a given node to be deleted . I got the solution for the problem . If you find any other way then please do inform me .

Comment: I used the word "pointer", because that's the word *you* used when you said "how handle can be used to return a pointer...".  Otherwise I would have said "reference", i.e., just a field of type `HeapNode` or `ApplicationObject` or whatever you call those types.   Maybe the suggestion from that paper isn't applicable to your case.  If you ended up with a `HashMap` (it's an index, not a handle), then perhaps that's what you need.

Comment: @Matt Okay . HashMap is an index not a pointer , but it served my purpose .